# How to query traces on component area in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

We set design rules to traces to meet required impedance. Those rules (clearance, width, ..) cannot be met near a component.

One solution is to query those out and set other (lower) rules (which does not significantly impact on impedance).

I have 2 rooms: one over USBHub named `NearUsbHub` and other over USBBridge named `NearUsbBridge`, where query seems works OK,

`InAnyDifferentialPair And (InComponent('U*') Or WithinRoom('NearUsbHub') Or WithinRoom('NearUsbBridge'))`

but `InComponent('U*')` select only pads - that are connected to differential pair nets.

Can I query traces on component area without setting new room on each matched component?

Comment: Have you tried asking this on one of the many Altium support groups before asking here?

Comment: I got some workaround answare for my PCB problem related to my desing. However I may need same question for KiCAD.